# Диагностика SMART говорит что диск исправен, но судя по данным он мёртв

Tags: linux, smart

Мой компьютер в целом работает нормально и никаких претензий к диску у меня нет, но сегодня установил стим и игры в нём периодически крашатся, а при запуске режима big picture остановился жёсткий диск, тогда я решил провести диагностику и вот что она показывает:

[image]

На самом деле нестабильная работа стима в линуксе, особенно на старом железе - это нормальное явление. Я просто удалю его и проблема решена. Любые другие программы работают хорошо, но меня смущают эти цифры. Здесь написано что обнаружено 208 миллионов ошибок чтения и 813 миллионов ошибок позиционирования, при этом диск считается исправным и состояние ОК?

Comment: Да, все хорошо, особенно если это сегейт (или кто там их сейчас перекупил) у них постоянно такая статистика. они видимо работают по принципу попал-не попал :)

Comment: @Mike можете скопировать этот комментарий в ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос. Спасибо :)

Comment: Если сильно боишься - переведи свой sata контроллер в биосе в режим ide и проверь поверхность винта прогой `MHDD` из под freedos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня уже десяток таких винтов с наработкой от 3 до 10 лет на десктопе. Наработка на твоем уже 5 лет, а это большой срок для диска. Он начинает просто тупить при произвольном доступе. Данные отдаются с задержкой и набивается буфер в оперативной памяти. Если памяти хватает, то можно стабильно пользоваться компьютером. Но современные игры это много данных в разных файлах.

813 миллионов это не много за 5 лет, посмотри насколько быстро это число растет.